# Email ID validation failed in ant

Tags: java, eclipse, email, ant, junit

I have written a JUnit testcase which validates email ID provided to it, this testcase passes email ID to validation framework which returns true or false, Validation framework class uses mail.jar to validate the email ID.

Now when I validate `firstlast@example.com` emailID using JUnit it runs to success.
Also I have written a ant script to run this tescases using commandline, and ant script also runs to success when I run for above emailID.

But when I run same testcase with email ID as `\"firstlast\"@example.com` (this email ID is specified in JUnit class's function, actual value that is received by validator class is `"firstlast@example.com"` double quotes are escaped here)
testcase runs to success with eclipse, but with ant script testcase fails.

I am not able to find why ant script fails to execute testcase whereas eclipse runs it success.

Email ID validation code is

```
public static boolean isValidEmailViaInternetAddress(String szEmailId)
{
    boolean bValid= true;

    try
    {
       InternetAddress oInternetAddress = new InternetAddress(szEmailId);
       oInternetAddress.validate();
    }
    // validate will throw the exception if emailid is not in proper format
    catch(AddressException e)
    {
       log.error("Could not verify emailID :" + szEmailId + ": Error is : " + e);
       bValid=false;
    }
    return bValid;
}`
```

Comment: Post the code. That'll help us.

Comment: There is one bug reported related to this http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=28527